# What is the difference between properties and parameters in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Here is a simple example of a class with some code (properties) inside the bracket

```
class Person(firstName: String) {
....
}
```

Now here is an example of a function with some code (parameters) inside the bracket

```
fun double(x: Int) {
...
}
```

I know this is a fundamental question but I am quite confused as a beginner.

Comment: Years later and I am still confused on the property vs param argument.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You pass *parameters* to functions and constructors, and *classes* have *properties*.

The constructor of the `Person` class in your example has a single parameter, and so does the `double` function. In this case, the `firstName` parameter is *not* a property!

To make it a property, you have to declare it so:

```
class Person(firstName: String) {

  val firstName : String = firstName
}
```

Kotlin allows this to be shorter, which makes the `firstName` parameter serve as a property:

```
class Person(val firstName: String)
```

Comment: That explains nothing; you just say that they are different.  Why would someone use one over the other?

Answer (score 7):

First, your `firstName` also is a [parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#parameters) rather than a [property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) in `Person` class.

```
//           v-- a parameter declared on primary constructor
class Person(firstName: String)
```

you can access a parameter declared on [primary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors) in `init` block or property/field declaration, for example:

```
class Person(firstName: String){
   val first:String
   init{ first=firstName }
}

class Person(firstName: String){
   val first:String = firstName
}

class Person(firstName: String){
   @JvmField val first:String = firstName
}
```

to make the `firstName` to a property you can using keyword `val` or `var`, for example:

```
//            v--- immutable property
class Person(val firstName: String)

//            v--- mutable property
class Person(var firstName: String)
```

a Kotlin property will generate getter/setter(?) and a [backing field(?)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) to java byte code. Take an example of a mutable property to java byte code as below:

```
public final class Person{
   private String firstName; // backing field

   //                   v--- parameter
   public Person(String firstName){ this.firstName = firstName; }

   //getter
   public final String getFirstName(){ return firstName; }

   //setter
   public final String setFirstName(String firstName){ this.firstName= firstName; }
}
```

a parameter only visible in function scope/constructor scope except parameter declared on primary constructor.

*Note*: a parameter is **immutable** like as java **effective-final** variables/parameters, so you can't reassign a parameter at all in Kotlin, for example:

```
fun foo(bar:String){
   bar = "baz"
// ^--- compile error  
}
```

Comment: So the real difference is that a parameter is ONLY accessible within a constructor, like `init()`.  Whereas properties are accessible throughout the class.  Essentially it's an issue of scope.  Right?

Answer (score 1):

properties and parameters  are different thinks:

*parameters*  : when we declare any function :

```
fun sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    return a + b
}
```

Function having two Int parameters with Int return type:

*Properties and Fields:*

Declaring Properties

Classes in `Kotlin` can have properties. These can be declared as mutable, using the `var` keyword or read-only using the `val` keyword.

```
class Address {
    var name: String = ...
    var street: String = ...
    var city: String = ...
    var state: String? = ...
    var zip: String = ...
}
```

To use a property, we simply refer to it by name, as if it were a field in Java:

```
fun copyAddress(address: Address): Address {
    val result = Address() // there's no 'new' keyword in Kotlin
    result.name = address.name // accessors are called
    result.street = address.street
    // ...
    return result
}
```

The full syntax for declaring a property is:

```
var <propertyName>[: <PropertyType>] [= <property_initializer>]
    [<getter>]
    [<setter>]
```

Comment: So what's the practical difference between `class foo(val x)` and `class foo(x)` other than what you call x (property or parameter)?  I guess what I (and the OP) are asking is, "What's the difference between a parameter and a 'val' property?"

Comment: Here x is a parameter has property immutable because of using Val to hold value of x.

Answer (score 0):

Properties and Parameter are two different things in Kotlin and many people have made it clear here. So, I will be just focusing on the difference between these two.
As much I have observed when you declare something as a parameter then it will not be the characteristic of objects so object can't access it but when you declare something as property then it will act be characteristic of object and you can access it inside the main function with the help of object name.
for example-

```
class dog( name : String) {
    init {
        bark(name)
    }
    fun bark (name: String){
        println("$name says whoo whoo")
    }
}
fun main(){
    val ob1 = dog("daisy")
    val ob2 = dog("rima")
//  println("${ob1.}")
}
```

here i have taken name as parameter so I am only able to pass it every time I create a new object, but I am unable to access it like 'ob1.name' in main function but if you will declare it as property you will be able to access it like that.